# How does Superconductiviy change in 2D and 1D?

Tags: superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate

I am just wondering if someone can talk about what can be carried over from the case of BCS theory in 3D down to lower dimensions. It seems there are many papers which write out BdG equations and work with these in dimensions lower than 3.

There are many issue which trip me up. For one, an arbitrarily weak interactions causes a bound state weather or not there is a Fermi sea, unlike in 3D. I recall reading a paper with an archaic version of Bosonization by Mattis and Lieb, which says there is no SC in 1D. However, there is a Kitaev model involving a p-wave SC in 1D with BCS like interaction terms, which hosts majorana fermions.

The question might be a bit open ended, but wouldn't we have to modify our BCS like theories so that they properly apply to lower dimensions? In what ways if so? Does it depend on the system? It just seems interactions are different in lower dimensions. Maybe using BCS as a sort of ansatz to work from the top down just gives useful predictions? Are there alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking there is no SC already in 2D. This is due to phase fluctuations (check "Berezinskiy-Kosterlitz-Thouless" phase transition), and is ultimately connected to the so-called Mermin-Wagner-Ho theorem that states there is no long-range order at finite temperature in 1- and 2D systems.

Now in the 1D Kitaev chain example the situation is different. First of all, in the original UFN paper Kitaev is doing just mean-field theory, so thermal fluctuations are not taken into account. However on a second thought you can realize this omission is not a problem, as for a Kitaev chain (at least in its original incarnation) the superconductivity is not "native" to the chain, but instead is induced by proximity to a nearby bulk 3D superconductor.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess in the anisotropic SC phase of the cuprates you could say you have a quasi-SC phase occurring in the CuO2 planes since I am pretty sure there is no Meissner effect till bulk SC is established